# Having issues with auto layout showing up different than preview

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on [Apples Swift Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1)

I've followed the UI layout but for some reason, when I hit play and the simulator pops up, my simulator shows up different than my preview. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: In which xcode version are you? Have you added all missing constraints?

Comment: Yeah I’ve followed the tutorial to a tee. I’m on the latest version

Comment: @Datsik I checked it, it is working fine, in your case pls add what constraints you've given to the stackView.

Comment: @dahiya_boy They're listed on the left side, do you need more?

Comment: @Datsik select distribution **FillEquallly**. and try

Answer (score 0):

I feel this question may help somebody in the future so I won't bother deleting it.

Through my own stupidity I ended up building the UI under the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` `ViewController` instead of the `Main.storyboard` `ViewController`. Simple fix -> Put things where it belongs!